# how to schedule a task to run at repeated intervals of 1 week or 2 weeks, in a java desktop/web application

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am working on an application to track search engine rankings of a web page.

What I want to do is, once a user starts the software, he enters the start date and time for one-time execution of the code to check search engine rankings, then every week a cron job(or similar) runs and refreshes the ranking data weekly/daily/fortnightly...

The data will be stored in either MySQL or Javadb. The application will be a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Application infra structure there are several opinions:

- [Quarz Framework](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)
- [Spring 3.0 @Scheduled Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)
- [EJB 3.1 @Schedule Annotation](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_16)